# Unable to mount my external hard disk

Tags: mount

I get this error message when I plug my external hard disk:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb2 at /media/vijay/7612-F96F: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdb2" "/media/vijay/7612-F96F"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'
```

Same problem came with previous hard disk but it was solved easily by `ntfsfix /dev/sdb2`, which isn't working for the new hard disk. :(

Comment: new hard drive seems to have exfat file system. how should ntfsfix (for NTFS file system) help? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the error properly, you will get clue about the problem and that is how you can get it solved.

The last part of the error message is: `mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'`. First of all it tells us this HDD was being mounted as `exfat` so it has nothing to do with `ntfs`. It also simply means your system does not recognize this file system.

If you are sure that the file system of the drive is `exfat`, you need to install `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils` using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Comment: But since I've just started learning about this OS, will you help me in understanding about the problem that i faced. I'll be thankful

Comment: Good :) see. there are different file system: FAT, NTFS,... one is exfat. Any operating system needs to know how to deal with each filesystem. in your case, ubuntu needed to know how to deal with exfat and because the definition was not included in it by default, we needed to install it. One of the best ways to come to solution is to read errors carefully. Errors are made in such a way to help the operator to come to know about the problem. There are lots of materials in internet as text and as video. This website is one of the best. Sometimes come, look around

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was quite an easy explanation to understand.